# How to call a string element and its index in Javscript?

Tags: javascript, string, indexing, element

I am trying to create the table which shows the array for names.

So the table would contain cells, one for index number, and the other one for its name.

The matter when the names are pushed in the array, the array does not show the all the elements I pushed.

The array which I push name by `.getElementById().value` does not return as

```
var ex_array = ['name1', 'name2',..],
```

but it shows like this.

```
var ex_array = ['n', 'a', 'm', 'e', '1', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', '2',...]
```

The way I am trying to is get elements by

```
var ex_array[0] = "name1"

var ex_array[1] = "name2"
```

for creating cell for

here is the code.

```js
namelist = [];

function push_name_list() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;

  namelist.push(name);
  var total = parseInt(namelist.length, 10);

  var newnamelist = "";
  
  for(var i=0; i < namelist.length; i++) {
    newnamelist = newnamelist + namelist[i] + "<br/>";
  }

  document.getElementById('array').innerHTML = newnamelist;
  
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <h1>Create Name List</h1>
    <!--Push name into the list.-->
    <span>Write a name.</span>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="name"/>
    <button onclick="push_name_list();">add</button>    

    <!--show elements in the array on the table.-->
    <table border="1" id="table" width = '200px'>
      <thead width ='100%'>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">
            Name List
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tableshow">
        <tr>
          <th id="number"></th>
          <td id="array"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="1" width ='30%'>
            total number of names :
          </th>
          <td id='total' width ='70%' margin ='auto'>
            actual total number
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly to me.

Comment: Do you mean that your variable namelist is wrong? For me it works perfectly fine?

Comment: So how is that ex_array related to that working snippet? It's not used in the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to replace `namelist[i] + "<br/>"` with `"<tr><th>"+(i+1)+"</th><th>"+namelist[i]+"</th></tr>";`

```js
namelist = [];

function push_name_list() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;

  namelist.push(name);
  var total = parseInt(namelist.length, 10);

  var newnamelist = "";
  
  for(var i=0; i < namelist.length; i++) {
    newnamelist = newnamelist + "<tr><th>"+(i+1)+"</th><th>"+namelist[i]+"</th></tr>";
  }

  document.getElementById('tableshow').innerHTML = newnamelist;
  
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
}

function createRow(index, value){
  return "<tr><td>"+index+"</td><td>"+value+"</td></tr>";
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Create Name List</h1>
    <!--Push name into the list.-->
    <span>Write a name.</span>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="name"/>
    <button onclick="push_name_list();">add</button>    

    <!--show elements in the array on the table.-->
    <table border="1" id="table" width = '200px'>
      <thead width ='100%'>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">
            Name List
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tableshow">
      
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="1" width ='30%'>
            total number of names :
          </th>
          <td id='total' width ='70%' margin ='auto'>
            actual total number
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use indexOf() function to get index of element.
I rewrite your function, hope it will be helpful.

```
namelist = [];

function push_name_list() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;

  namelist.push(name);
  var total = parseInt(namelist.length, 10);

  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;

    document.getElementById('tableshow').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<tr><th id="number">' + namelist.indexOf(name) +'</th><td id="array">' + name + '</td</tr>');

}
```

Comment: God, i'm literally screaming just after running your code. Thanks for teaching.